# Access to Controller's method parameter values from Spring MVC interceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm developing a REST webservice with Spring MVC and I've implemented a custom annotation in order to annotate controller methods with it. This annotation may include a SpEL expression which I must evaluate considering controller method argument values. So, my idea is to implement a Spring MVC interceptor for this but the parameter HandlerMethod in the preHandle method is just a way to identify the method and does not provide access to controller method argument values. So, the only approach I can think of is to develop a Spring AOP aspect and intercept all the calls to annotated methods. By the way, I need access to the request, so if I go by the AOP way, all the annotated methods should include an argument with the request.

So, my question is: Is there any way to access the method argument values from thr Spring MVC interceptor or should I go the Spring AOP way?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding what you are trying to do, but doesn't `HandlerMethod.getMethodParameters()` return the information you need?

Comment: @geoand from MethodParameter javadoc "Helper class that encapsulates the specification of a method parameter"

Comment: You mean that you need the actual arguments that will be passed to the method?

Comment: Yes, in order to evaluate possible SpEL expression with them.

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't have any suggestions on that. Could you explain a little why you need to evaluate SpEL in an interceptor? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The API will use an external API platform provider, providing authorization and metric reporting. The metric depends on the method argument, (for example, number of profiles submitted in the call). The SpEL expression pretends to evaluate metric values.

Comment: I see. Can you obtain the arguments through the raw HTTP request without too much hassle? That would seem to me like the most straight forward way to go with interceptors

Comment: Not easy, as the request will contain a json which I'd prefer automatically unmarshalled by Jackson in order to access the object graph when evaluating the expression.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot use the controller method parameter in the `preHandle` method of an interceptor, because at the time of calling it, the parameters of the controller method have not been constructed (except for request and response).

So you will have to go the AOP way (do not forget to implement a method in your controllers ...) like explained in JavaBond answer. But thanks to spring framework, you can avoid that all the annotated methods should include an argument with the request. `RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()` gives you a `RequestAttributes` object. If you know that your request **is** a `HttpServletRequest`, you can cast it to a `ServletRequestAttributes` and then access the native request via the `getRequest()` method :

```
RequestAttributes reqAttr = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
HttpServletRequest req = ((ServletRequestAttributes) reqAttr).getRequest();
```

Comment: There is a small syntax error in the code above. Should be:  `code           RequestAttributes reqAttr = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();  
        HttpServletRequest req = ((ServletRequestAttributes) reqAttr).getRequest();`

Answer (score 5):

You should go the AOP way.

Write an `Around` advice against your custom annotation. The around advice should have a `ProceedingJoinPoint` argument. Using this you can get the annotated methods arguments values via `proceedingJoinPoint.getArgs()`

Sample advice shown below

```
@Around("@annotation(yourCustomAnnotation)")
public Object arooundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinpoint,
        YourCustomAnnotation yourCustomAnnotation) throws Throwable {

    Object args[] = joinpoint.getArgs();
    // iterate over the args[] array to get the annotated method arguments
    return joinpoint.proceed();
}
```

Comment: as I've said in my question I can't get access to controller method actual arguments from the Interceptor. As far as I know, HandlerMethod is just a way to identify the method which will be invoked.

Comment: thanks for your answers. This is one of the options I was thinking of. Going the AOP way I should include the request to all the annotated methods. I thought the interceptor was a more natural way.

Comment: glad to help :) As Serge mentioned in his answer you need not include the request as annotated method argument. let know if you are able to achieve your goal.

Comment: thanks for your interest. Currently implementing it via AOP and looks fine.